# Properties of the Taylor Series

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion

I am studying the Iaylor series at this moment. However, I do not know how to prove the 4 properties of the Taylor series (seen in the picture). Unfortunately, I cannot find any proof anywhere.

It would be really great if someone can provide me with the proof.

Thank you in advance

! [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4N60.jpg.

Comment: All four of these are essentially proved by just writing out the definition of $T_n$, namely that $T_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{n!} (x - x_0)^k$ and doing a couple lines of algebra. The first property, for example, follows from the fact that $\sum (b t_n + c s_n) = b \sum t_n + c \sum s_n$.